# Md5: реализация алгоритма на javascript

Tags: javascript, md5

Привет всем! 
Решил подробно разобраться с алгоритмом md5 и возникло несколько вопросов.
Разбираю его по реализации на javascript, приведенной тут http://javascript.ru/php/md5
Вопрос: почему там именно такая реализация функции addUnsigned()? почему ее нельзя было записать просто сложением двух переменных?

Comment: Во-первых там немного больше, чем просто сложение двух переменных, во-вторых у хэш-функций есть такая особенность, что они независимы от конца потока - для того, чтобы получить хэш от (А + Б) байтов, можно получить хэш от первых А байтов, а потом проапдейтить полученное значение последующими Б байтами. Я подозреваю, что одна из причин существования этой функции - логическое разделение.

Comment: А не могли бы Вы подробнее расписать, что там "немного больше, чем просто сложение двух переменных" ?
И почему я задался таким вопросом: нашёл другую реализацию алгоритма на C++ (http://www.vr-online.ru/content/md5-na-c-shag-za-shagom-1581), в которой используется просто сложение переменных.

Comment: причина - в javascript неявное приведение типов данных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такая реализация сложения нужна для эмуляции беззнакового сложения, которое, в свою очередь, необходимо для реализации MD5. В данном случае под беззнаковым сложением подразумевается не сложение модулей двух чисел, а сложение двух чисел так, как если бы они хранились в беззнаковом виде. Знаковые целые хранятся в [дополнительном коде](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)) в виде `[1 бит - знак][31 бит - значение]` (таким образом в 4 байта влезают целые числа от -2147483648 до 2147483647), а в беззнаковых числах все 32 бита отводятся под значение (диапазон значений таких чисел - от 0 до 4294967295). В C/C++ есть беззнаковые типы данных, в JavaScript их нет. Поэтому приходится их эмулировать при помощи битовых манипуляций.